# Clip Line Layer to Polygon but retain the Lines outside the polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, clip

I want to clip a line layer to a polygon layer, but retain the lines outside the polygons.

Can anybody assist me in doing this please?

On the image included, the lines are in red and the polygon in green.

I am using QGIS 3.22.4

Comment: The image is missing.

Comment: Try Difference processing algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to only keep the lines that do not intersects the polygons you could use the "extract by location" tool.

*Layer to select from* : your line layer

*Additional layer* : your polygon layer

*Geometric predicate* : disjoint

[image]